# What happens if i move a file from a Bitlocker drive?

Tags: encryption, disk-encryption, bitlocker

If I move a file from a bitlocker enabled drive/partition to a non bitlocker drive/partition what happens to the file?

Does it stay encrypted but unreadable?

Does encryption disappear?

Answer (score 3):

The encryption only applies to the disk that is BitLocker encrypted. Just as the files are automatically decrypted when you open them, they are decrypted before moving them to the non-BitLocker drive.

According to Microsoft on their [Help protect your files using BitLocker Drive Encryption](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/protect-files-bitlocker-drive-encryption#1TC=windows-8) page:

> However, if you copy these files to another drive or a different PC, they're automatically decrypted.

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem to be the case any more.  The only way to sneakernet them into a different computer is to remove all encryption and protection before copying them.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1112268)

Comment: This is a function perhaps of the policies governing data on the computers you use. It is NOT how BitLocker behaves.

Comment: So, please explain that in an answer, thanks.  What, precisely, are the policies governing this?